# Mouse cursor in the Rstudio IDE keeps disappearing in the R script section

Tags: r, cursor, mouse

I have downloaded R and Rstudio the latest versions respectively.

But whenever I am practising writing some code in the R script section of the IDE in R studio after a few minutes the mouse cursor keeps disappearing and I can’t write anymore code. It’s very frustrating. Is there a problem in the program? I never used to have this problem with the old version of R studio.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this help? https://community.rstudio.com/t/poblem-with-rstudio-cursor-and-prompt/35748

Comment: No it doesn't help. Someone else on Rstudio community is also experiencing the same issue he said he will log it with gitihub.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is not the same problem, but I recently had issues with the pointer using R. I fixed in this way: `Ctrl + R`, write "Control mouse" and then in Pointer Options deselect the option: "Hide pointer while writing".